# Check all the view's background in an if statement in Android?

Tags: android, if-statement

I have many buttons(81) from the left and right part of my layout. All in all, I have 162 buttons. I put those buttons to Button[] and I handle it properly.

```
    private int[] right_lung = { R.id.btn_right_106, R.id.btn_right_113,
        R.id.btn_right_114, R.id.btn_right_115, R.id.btn_right_116, R.id.btn_right_121,
        R.id.btn_right_122, R.id.btn_right_123, R.id.btn_right_124, R.id.btn_right_125,
        R.id.btn_right_129, R.id.btn_right_130, R.id.btn_right_131, R.id.btn_right_132,
        R.id.btn_right_133, R.id.btn_right_134, R.id.btn_right_137, R.id.btn_right_138,
        R.id.btn_right_139, R.id.btn_right_140, R.id.btn_right_141, R.id.btn_right_142,
        R.id.btn_right_143, R.id.btn_right_145, R.id.btn_right_146, R.id.btn_right_147,
        R.id.btn_right_148, R.id.btn_right_149, R.id.btn_right_150, R.id.btn_right_151,
        R.id.btn_right_152, R.id.btn_right_153, R.id.btn_right_154, R.id.btn_right_155,
        R.id.btn_right_156, R.id.btn_right_157, R.id.btn_right_158, R.id.btn_right_159,
        R.id.btn_right_160, R.id.btn_right_161, R.id.btn_right_162, R.id.btn_right_163,
        R.id.btn_right_164, R.id.btn_right_165, R.id.btn_right_166, R.id.btn_right_167,
        R.id.btn_right_168, R.id.btn_right_169, R.id.btn_right_170, R.id.btn_right_171,
        R.id.btn_right_172, R.id.btn_right_173, R.id.btn_right_174, R.id.btn_right_175,
        R.id.btn_right_176, R.id.btn_right_177, R.id.btn_right_178, R.id.btn_right_179,
        R.id.btn_right_180, R.id.btn_right_181, R.id.btn_right_182, R.id.btn_right_183,
        R.id.btn_right_184, R.id.btn_right_185, R.id.btn_right_186, R.id.btn_right_187,
        R.id.btn_right_188, R.id.btn_right_189, R.id.btn_right_190, R.id.btn_right_191,
        R.id.btn_right_192, R.id.btn_right_194, R.id.btn_right_195, R.id.btn_right_196,
        R.id.btn_right_197, R.id.btn_right_198, R.id.btn_right_199, R.id.btn_right_200,
        R.id.btn_right_205, R.id.btn_right_206, R.id.btn_right_207 };

private Button[] btn_right = new Button[right_lung.length];

private int[] left_lung = { R.id.btn_left_7, R.id.btn_left_13, R.id.btn_left_14,
        R.id.btn_left_15, R.id.btn_left_16, R.id.btn_left_20, R.id.btn_left_21,
        R.id.btn_left_22, R.id.btn_left_23, R.id.btn_left_24, R.id.btn_left_27,
        R.id.btn_left_28, R.id.btn_left_29, R.id.btn_left_30, R.id.btn_left_31,
        R.id.btn_left_32, R.id.btn_left_34, R.id.btn_left_35, R.id.btn_left_36,
        R.id.btn_left_37, R.id.btn_left_38, R.id.btn_left_39, R.id.btn_left_40,
        R.id.btn_left_41, R.id.btn_left_42, R.id.btn_left_43, R.id.btn_left_44,
        R.id.btn_left_45, R.id.btn_left_46, R.id.btn_left_47, R.id.btn_left_48,
        R.id.btn_left_49, R.id.btn_left_50, R.id.btn_left_51, R.id.btn_left_52,
        R.id.btn_left_53, R.id.btn_left_54, R.id.btn_left_55, R.id.btn_left_56,
        R.id.btn_left_57, R.id.btn_left_58, R.id.btn_left_59, R.id.btn_left_60,
        R.id.btn_left_61, R.id.btn_left_62, R.id.btn_left_63, R.id.btn_left_64,
        R.id.btn_left_65, R.id.btn_left_66, R.id.btn_left_67, R.id.btn_left_68,
        R.id.btn_left_69, R.id.btn_left_70, R.id.btn_left_71, R.id.btn_left_72,
        R.id.btn_left_73, R.id.btn_left_74, R.id.btn_left_75, R.id.btn_left_76,
        R.id.btn_left_77, R.id.btn_left_78, R.id.btn_left_79, R.id.btn_left_80,
        R.id.btn_left_81, R.id.btn_left_82, R.id.btn_left_83, R.id.btn_left_84,
        R.id.btn_left_85, R.id.btn_left_86, R.id.btn_left_87, R.id.btn_left_88,
        R.id.btn_left_89, R.id.btn_left_90, R.id.btn_left_91, R.id.btn_left_92,
        R.id.btn_left_93, R.id.btn_left_94, R.id.btn_left_95, R.id.btn_left_98,
        R.id.btn_left_99, R.id.btn_left_100, };

private Button[] btn_left = new Button[left_lung.length];
```

Whenever I click on the button, just like in mine sweeper game, many buttons are randomly opened. And when it is opened, I am changing its background into **R.drawable.affected**. The goal of the game is to open all the buttons in left and right. My question is this, how can I check if all of the buttons are set in R.drawable.affected? Because after that, I will execute a method that will congratulate the user. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < btn_right.length; i++) {
   final int a = i;
   int counter_total_affected = 0;
   btn_right[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (counter == 1) {
                   right_lung.add(a);
                   btn_right[a].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
           counter_total_affected++;
              } else if (counter == 2) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                       int n = i;
                       right_lung.add(a + n);
                   }

                   try {
                       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                           int n = i;
                           btn_right[a + n].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                           counter_total_affected++;
                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }

              } else if (counter == 3) {
                   right_lung.add(a);
                   btn_right[a].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                   counter_total_affected++;

              } else if (counter == 4) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                       int n = i;
                       right_lung.add(a + n);
                   }

                   try {
                       for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                           int n = i;
                           btn_right[a + n].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                           counter_total_affected++;
                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

              } else if (counter == ...) {
                   //statements...
              }  else if (counter_total_affected == (btn_left.length + btn_right.length)) {
                    //CONGRATULATORY METHOD
              }
              counter++;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the counter each time you change background of button and compare its value with length of button array. if both are same that means, all button backgrounds are set.

Try this :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < btn_right.length; i++) {
       final int b = i;
       btn_right[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                if btn_right[i].getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
                (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.affected).getConstantState()))
                 {
                          if(counter == btn_right.length){
                           //Congratulate user...
                          }
                 }else{   
                       btn_right[b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                       counter++;
                 }
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

U can set Tag:

```
for (int i = 0; i < btn_right.length; i++) {
   final int b = i;
   btn_right[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (counter == 1) {
                   right_affected.add(b);
                   btn_right[b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                   btn_right[b].setTag('1');
              } else {
                   //some stuff here...
              }
          }
}
```

after congratulate the user set its Tag to `0`.

EDIT:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayofId =new ArrayList<Integer>();
  @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (counter == 1) {
                       right_affected.add(b);
                       btn_right[b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.affected);
                      arrayofId.add(b);//need to convert int to Integer.
                  } else {
                       //some stuff here...
                  }
              }
```

To congratulate:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayofId.size();i++)
{
// you can get here id of effected buttons
}
```

Comment: after if (counter == 1), i have another 10 else ifs for that. Do you mean, from all of them, I'll be putting setTag()?

Comment: yeah, i need to check if all of my buttons are affected then by that time, I'll execute my congratulatory method...

Comment: ohh.. then u can take one empty arraylist of int& then put their id while changing its background.Check my edited answer.